# NAS with a public IP inaccessible from a local network other than by FTP

Tags: networking, router, ftp, nas

I have a NAS with a public IP x.y.z.10 and a computer with a public IP x.y.z.20 which can connect to it via AFP or whatever the heck Windows uses when you write \\server\folder (SMB?), however when I try to connect from another computer (LAN private IP 192.168.1.100) via a router (WAN public IP x.y.z.30), I can only use FTP (or HTTP to access the web interface). The NAS does not support SFTP.

How can I access the NAS from the LAN in a way that will allow me to mount it as a network drive and make changes to files without first downloading them?

Comment: Why would they have a public IP if you use `\\server` to access them? Usually you would use SMB or CIFS for this. It would actually depend on the NAS and what it's supporting. Depending on it this doesn't work over Internet and you would usually rather use something like WebDAV.

Comment: @Seth Bad network infrastructure (it's not mine). I'm also not a Windows user and know little about networking, so I don't even quite get how a computer connected to WAN can see other devices on the network, i.e. everything with the public IP of x.y.z.1–255. Anyway, the NAS does support WebDAV so I'm going to look into that, thank you.

Comment: It would really depend on the NAS. A share is usually accessed using SMB which is also compatible to CIFS (which is derived from SMB). As CIFS stands for "Common Internet File System" it's not unexpected that it might work but if it was a really old NAS it might not support that. On test you could do is whenever you can access the server if you use the FQDN (`\\server.domain.tld`) instead of the shorthand as the resolution of the name might just fail. Otherwise a FW or something could be interfering as low ports are used for SMB/CIFS.

Comment: @Seth Thank you for your help, I've managed to solve it by using the IP address directly rather than the server name (it's embarrassing it didn't occur to me sooner), i.e. \\x.y.z.10 and the NAS was mapped as a drive without an issue even though I can't see it in the Network folder… I'm quite interested in knowing the reason for this but in any case, job done.

Comment: You mean you can't see it if you click "network"? Depending on circumstances it might be using NETBIOS and depending on the network architecture that might not propagate.

Comment: @Seth Yes, that's what I meant, and wow, Windows never ceases to baffle me. For example, different network hosts load on different devices and sometimes even on the same device and I have to refresh a couple of times before I get the ones I need. Sometimes those network hosts don't show up at all but accessing them via that \\server notation works (not via the router though). On OS X and Linux, no issues at all.